# How to send the notification bar back up programatically?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I researched and the only answers I could find either told:

1. How to disable the notification bar from being pulled down.
2. How to cancel a notification using:

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       notificationManager.cancel(0);

Both of these aren't what I require as the notification gets cancelled fine. I've set two actions in my notification: 'Dismiss' and 'Open Activity'. As the name implies, upon clicking both, the above code executes and clears the notification but doesn't cause the notification bar from going back up. This is needed, specially when the second Notification Action causes an Activity launch.

I tried on Android Lollipop and Nougat and the notification bar didn't go back up in either. So if someone could kindly tell me if it is even possible and how. 
Thanks.

The code for building the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder
            .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(message).setWhen(when)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Kindly record your Voice")
            .setColor(Color.RED);


    notificationIntent = new Intent(this,ReminderReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction("Record");
    PendingIntent pendIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark, "Record", pendIntent1);


    notificationIntent2 = new Intent(this, ReminderReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent2.setAction("Dismissed");

    PendingIntent pendIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, notificationIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.starticon, "Dismiss", pendIntent2);

    notificationIntent3 = new Intent(this, CancelReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, notificationIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setDeleteIntent(pendIntent3);

    notification = builder.build();


    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Have you tried .setAutoCancel(true) in notification builder?

Comment: Yes I have. Doesn't help.

Comment: Are you using this code in the activity? 
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); notificationManager.cancel(0);

And why are you setting the same notification id for all notifications, do you want only one notification to be present?

Comment: Yes. Its a single notification, with all those separate actions. Plus, the code for cancelation is written in a Broadcast receiver.

Comment: Well on any action click that code should work internally, so there is no need for it. Anyway, you are setting notification id to 1
(notificationManager.notify(1, notification);), but you are trying to close notification with id 0 (notificationManager.cancel(0);). Try not to use delete intent at all (unless you need to know that notification was cancelled for other reasons) or use the same notification id.

Comment: That notification is generated for another reason.
Again, the notifications are being cancelled perfectly finely. The issue is that after its gone, the bar notification panel still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might seem weird, but the notification bar doesn't go up when there are other notifications present. If yours is the only notification, the bar slides up automatically upon clicking.

Comment: Works! Thats the only reason the bar wasn't going back up.